# unittest django login from auth

Tags: django, authorization, python-unittest

I want to write simple test for login:
    view.py:

```
def login(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = auth.authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
    else:
        pass

test.py:

class TestSuite(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='jacob', email='jacob@…', password='top_secret')

    def test_user_can_login(self):
        r = self.factory.post("/login", {"username": "jacob", "password": "top_secret"})
        login(r)
```

When I run test (by manage.py test) I recive:

```
System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_user_can_login (Users.tests.TestSuite)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bbb\auto\Contract\Users\tests.py", line 16, in test_user_c
an_login
    login(r)
  File "C:\Users\bbb\auto\Contract\Users\views.py", line 13, in login
    auth.login(request, user)
  File "C:\Users\bbb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pac
kages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 126, in login
    if SESSION_KEY in request.session:
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'session'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.080s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

What should I do to enable session in test or what is better way to write this test?

Comment: Note that Django provides [authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views). I recommend you use the login view rather than writing your own.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use the test client instead of the `RequestFactory`.

```
class TestSuite(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='jacob', email='jacob@…', password='top_secret')

    def test_user_can_login(self):
        response = self.client.post("/login", {"username": "jacob", "password": "top_secret"})
        ...
```